# How to test RewardVideo in Facebook Instant Game?

Tags: facebook-instant-games, facebook-monetization-manager

This is my code.

```
  var ad;
  FBInstant.getRewardedVideoAsync('1234_1234')
    .then(function(rewardedVideo) {
      if(typeof rewardedVideo !== 'undefined'){
        if(typeof rewardedVideo.getPlacementID() === 'undefined'){
          console.log('can not get placement ID')
        }
        ad = rewardedVideo;
        return rewardedVideo.loadAsync()
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('rewardedVideo is undefined'))
      }
    })
    .then(function(){ //adv loaded
      console.log('adv loaded')
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.code, error.message);
    });
```

I always get {code: "ADS_NO_FILL", message: 'No fill'}. The document said: "ADS_NO_FILL string We were not able to serve ads to the current user. This can happen if the user has opted out of interest-based ads on their device, or if we do not have ad inventory to show for that user."

But my app still in development.

Answer (score 1):

If you're regularly getting this error it is highly likely there is some kind of misconfiguration in your Audience Network settings.

Check to ensure that:

1. under the Manage Property option in [Monetization Manager](https://business.facebook.com/pub/property) the platform type is Instant Games and you have an ad space configured as shown: [image: image showing Instant Games ad space]
2. you have a valid payment account specified
3. if the above are set and ads still aren't served, contact the Audience Network team for support from the help link at the bottom of [Monetization Manager](https://business.facebook.com/pub/property).

Comment: any idea why there is no Instant Games available as a platform anywhere in my Monetization Manager? There are only ios app, android app and site to choose.

Answer (score 1):

These days I had the same problem as you, but found the solution!

The fact that your app is "in development" doesn't mean that you can't see live ads. You have the right code in your Facebook Instant Game, i guess you have obtained a real `INTERSTITIAL_PLACEMENT_ID` especially for your Game using the Monetization Manager.

Once you get the `ADS_NO_FILL` error, the status in Monetization Manager changes from *Awaiting integration* into *Successful ad delivery* besides the error. To view live ads, you need to specify your payment information (your personal and bank data, especially the IBAN number for the income account). Then
live ads will be served (regardless of your game being not approved by Facebook).